# LinearLayout not rendering

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-view

I want to create a login screen. I want to have the heading at the top, leave some white space and then have the user name and passwords each in one line. Then, I want to leave some more white space at the bottom.

Currently, I haven't tried to put the password TextView and EditTect in a single line because there is some error with the LinearLayout corresponding to the user name due to which it is not rendering. Could you please help me figure out? My XML file is below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/welcome_message"
        android:textSize="20sp" />



    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="4" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="User Name" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Password" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="4" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look if this what are you looking for:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="welcome_message"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="Login:"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:ems="10" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="4" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_senha"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Senha:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_senha"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. This does work, but I will really be grateful if you could point out the mistakes in my xml too :-)

Comment: I think I have formed a hypothesis on why my xml wasn't giving the intended output myself but still, please do correct me if I am wrong. If the LinearLayout has children and we are determining its height using android:layout_weight, we shouldn't put its height as "0sp", but rather "wrap_content". Am I correct?

Comment: I'm not an expert in XML but ,if you are using weight to determining its height it doesn't matter

Comment: to be true it is better to use "0sp"

Comment: A nice thing that I advice is to use relative layout like @Amourreux said, but use it inside a linear layout, the lineatlayout is going to determine its height and the relative the positions of buttons, text...,

Comment: It doesn't work if I use "0sp" there. Just change "0sp" for the inner LinearLayout to "wrap_content" and it will start showing. I was also under the impression I should be using "0sp", hence the question :)

Comment: okay, I get the point of using RelativeLayout now :) I will do that from the next time.

Comment: For example take the <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1" >
and change for:

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

Comment: check out this edited code using the weight to determine its height

Comment: Why did you change the weight from 0.1 to 1 in your code snippet in the comments when you changed the height?

Comment: And I think you are right that the height doesn't matter even in the parent layout if it is determined by layout_weight. This is because when I changed the height of LinearLayout from "wrap_content" to "0sp", there was no change. But then why does the LinearLayout in my incorrect XML in the question appear only when I change its height to "wrap_content"?

Answer (score 1):

use layout margin and padding settings to leaving space for views.
i recommend using relative layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="welcome_message"
        android:textSize="20sp" />



    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="4" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="User Name" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Password" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I didn't want to hard code values since I wanted my app to work fine on all devices (tablet or mobile). Even though I am optimizing for one (a tablet), I still didn't want to screw up the display on mobiles. Is their a way to do this using margins or paddings but without using hard-coded values? :)

Comment: Also, could you guide me on when to use relative layout verusus linear? Please forgive me if this is a novice question (I admit to being a starter in developing applications on Android). I admit I didn't really think much before choosing linear layout since I saw quite a few similar examples doing that for login screens.

Comment: @Shubham Goyal using same layout for every screen size and orientation is a quite challenge. you can create separate layouts for each screen size and orientation. that way you can manage to do more good looking screens layouts. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @ShubhamGoyal secend thing i forget to mention.  their is a way to do this using margins or paddings but without using hard-coded values. Create values-sw600dp, values-sw720dp-land  folders under res folder of your app. In that folders create dimens.xml file. inside of this file sould be like this ;
<resources>

    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">128dp</dimen>

</resources>
For more info please look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html